# Why does Faraday's law work?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

A thin bar is moving parallel to a current and we want to evaluate the tension between the two extremes of the bar.

[image]

What I did was applying Faraday's law to the bar, considering the flux of the magnetic field through the surface: $S(t)=v\cdot t \cdot l$, but I have no clue why this works since the area of the bar is its length times its width, while here we're considering a surface that is not that of the bar itself:

[image].

Maybe my misunderstanding is due to something I don't know about Faraday's law. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a voltmeter linked to both ends of the bar. Let's say the whole thing forms a rectangular circuit. At $t=0$, the rectangular area is $A$. Then at $t=t_{f}$, the area of the circuit changes to $A'$

From your example, it is not clear how you measure the tension, that's why you got confused.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of problem it is usually easier to understand *intuitively* what happens if instead of using Faraday's law you apply Lorentz's force law according to which $\mathbf F = q(\mathbf E + \mathbf v \times \mathbf B)$. Here the *external* $q\mathbf E$ field is zero, so you only have to deal with the force $\mathbf F = q \mathbf v \times \mathbf B$ acting on the free electrons within the *nonmagnetic*, say, copper metal bar. This force will be pointing along the bar to the right because $q$ is negative. At equilibrium, therefore, you will have negative charges accumulating on the right end and equal amount of positive charges on the left, and this is what your voltmeter will measure. Of course, at equilibrium, the internally induced electric force $q\mathbf E$ is exactly compensated by the magnetic force so that no more charges get accumulated.

Comment: Yes I know, but that's the way my professor solved the exercise as well so I wanted to understand why it works

Comment: To see why that works you need to apply Faraday's law $emf=-\frac{d\Phi}{dt}$ to a moving surface consisting of the bar and an arbitrary contour connecting its ends. When you take the time derivative of that moving surface integral you actually get a $\mathbf {v} \times \mathbf{B}$ term that is equal to the full contour integral of $qE$ which just the $emf$.